# How can i know if switching to a particular VisualState is over or not?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How can i get notified when switching to a particular VisualState is complete or not?

Example. `VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "UnloadState", true);`

In above case i want to get notified when switched to UnloadedState is completed.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is in a `UserControl` then its quite straight-forward, you can simply add a completed event handler to the `StoryBoard` associated with the state:-

```
<VisualState x:Name="UnloadState">
   <Storyboard Completed="UnloadState_Completed">
```

Then in code:-

```
 void UnloadState_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    // Do stuff when complete
 }
```

However in a templated control things are a little more complicated.  You won't know whether the template even has such a state and you can't wire up with Xaml.  However in `OnApplyTemplate` you should be able to find the `VisualState` with `FindName` then you can attach the event handler in code.  You should hold the VisualState object in a field so that you can handle detaching the event handler correctly.